# Heroku stuck in "Build in progress"

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have created a server using heroku, the problem that when i deployed my application it showed to me the following error message:
[image]
now the application when i try to make other deploy or build it says you have reached your build limit, already passed 3 days and its still stuck in "Build in progress" there is any way to kill the build to start a new one?

Comment: I suggest going to http://help.heroku.com/ and providing the Request ID as the error message says.

Comment: I tried to create a ticket, to report the code, but it says "Technical support for Free applications is provided by the online community." so... here i am with no luck.